# Options to Subscribing to a Google Pub Sub Topic to Pull Data from GCP to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, google-cloud-pubsub

We have a customer that publishes data to Google Pub Sub Topic and allows us in read only mode to consume the messages.   We would like to utilize AWS tools to accomplish this pipeline.  What would be the best method to execute this?

We have looked at SNS, SQS and using a lamba.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Pull data from GCP to AWS but to *where exactly*? Do you want to process them on the fly? Store them? Save them?

Comment: Ideally grab the json, call a lambda to parse and store in CSV in S3

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no native solution - you will need to create a a Pub/Sub trigger on a Google cloud function which then ingests and forwards on the message to the relative AWS SQS queue (which is the direct equivalent). You can then process the messages on the other side using SQS triggers or manual polling. Why can't you parse within GCP and then perhaps only store the file in S3?

Comment: We have looked at both options...the GCP Environment is not ours so we were hoping to find a way to just grab the message.   Would Amazon MSK (Kafka) solve our problem?